# installing mod_ssl causes httpd to segmentation fault

Tags: apache, mod-ssl

I am running apache

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 16 2014 14:48:21
```

and it runs fine but when I do yum install mod_ssl, apache seg faults. It seg faults right away when I try to list modules using httpd -M.

```
$ httpd -M
Segmentation fault
```

If I try to restart apache, it seg faults again

```
$ sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: /bin/bash: line 1:  1627 Segmentation fault      /usr/sbin/httpd
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with CentOS it seems, because I found this resource:
https://chrisjean.com/adding-ssl-support-to-apache-on-centos/

so all I had to do was make sure Apache was loading the SSL module and everything is ok. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.